# Не происходит связывания данных DataContext и UserControl DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день. Не происходит связывания данных DataContext и UserControl DependencyProperty.

При этом если связывать со стандартным элементом, а не с UserControl, все работает отлично. Замечено, что в UserControl участок кода SetValueDp не выполняется, присваивания никакого не идет. Такое ощущение, что я что-то упустил, прошу помочь)

Пример кода:
Window.xaml

```
<Window ... >
  <Grid>
    <gui:TestUserControl Text="{Binding SomeTextValue}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window.cs

```
...
public MainForm(IMainFormViewModel viewModel)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

MainFormViewModel.cs

```
...
public string SomeTextValue
{
  get
  {
    return _someTextValue;
  }
  set
  {
    _someTextValue = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
...
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
{
  this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
    handler(this, e);
  }
}
...
```

TestUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="vpngraph.src.Gui.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

TestUserControl.cs

```
public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValueDp(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string), typeof (TestUserControl), null);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value,
        [CallerMemberName] string p = null)
    {
        SetValue(property, value);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    public TestUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: В `SetValueDp` и не будет заходить - установка свойств идёт напрямую через `SetValue`.

А вот здесь, если не биндингом, а просто текст написать какой, будет работать?
<gui:TestUserControl Text="{Binding SomeTextValue}"/>

Comment: @Chaek: `SetValueDp` и не будет вызываться, т. к. никто не гарантиерует вам доступ к dependency property через setter. (Поэтому верните нормальную реализацию dependency property.)

Попробуйте для начала вместо `<gui:TestUserControl Text="{Binding SomeTextValue}"/>` написать `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextValue}"/>` и сообщите, что видите.

Попробуйте ещё вместо передачи `null` использовать `DependencyProperty.Register` с тремя аргументами.

Comment: Обычный текст работает.
Разобрался, решается проблема изменением строки на <gui:TestUserControl Text="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding SomeTextValue}" />, 2 суток на это убил))

Comment: Вообще, должно быть достаточно поменять местами строку установки конекста и инициализации контрола. Но, как писал @VladD, так делать не самая хорошая идея

Answer (score 5):

Ошибка в `TestUserControl`, в строке `this.DataContext = this;`.

Это кажется удобным для имплементации XAML-части, но это сбивает `Binding`, так как после этого код `{Binding SomeTextValue}` ищет `SomeTextValue` в самом `TestUserControl`'е!

Не делайте так!

Есть несколько способов. Либо делайте честный binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="vpngraph.src.Gui.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox"
                 Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock"
                   Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Либо дайте имя корневому элементу, чтобы было проще:

```
<UserControl x:Class="vpngraph.src.Gui.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="Root">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Root}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Root}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Либо поменяйте DataContext не на корневом элементе:

```
<UserControl x:Class="vpngraph.src.Gui.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                      AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Тогда и не будет разницы между `<gui:TestUserControl Text="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding SomeTextValue}"/>` и `<gui:TestUserControl Text="{Binding SomeTextValue}"/>`.

Вообще, для контрола устанавливать `DataContext` самому себе — плохая идея.

Comment: Я несколько месяцев с этим боролся. У меня то ничего не получалось (как у автора), то вылетал StackOverflowException (если имена свойств совпадали в модели и контроле). Я уже решил, что создание полноценных контролов - это не мое. А вы одним предложением объяснили в чем дело! Спасибищщще!!! :)

Comment: @iRumba: Пожалуйста! Рад, что пригодилось не только автору вопроса.

Comment: А за место 3 способа, можно сделать так в  конструкторе TestUserControl прописать 
mainStackPanel.DataContext = this;
поидее тоже самое, или нет?

Comment: @virty90: Можно и так, конечно.