# Изменения стиля внутренних контролов у UserControl'а

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно делают такие вещи. У меня есть UserControl -
 SearchBox, который собран из TextBox и Button. Мне бы хотелось его сделать более универсальным, поэтому я не устанавливал почти никакие свойства, аля Background, Foreground, FontFamily, FontSize и тд, у внутренних контролов TextBox и Button( в основном эти свойства перенаправлял наружу с помощью `TemplateBinding`, чтобы эти контролы брали значения у UserControl'а.

Суть вопроса в следующем: Как в дальшейшем определять стиль отдельно для Button и отдельно для TextBox'а внутри этого UserControl'а, не прибегая к свойству `Template`?
Если нужен код, моего UserControl'а, то вот частичный:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <local:InputBox PlaceHolder="{Binding PlaceHolder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                            />

            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Content="&#xf002;"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"
                    Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            </Button>

        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: А зачем вам вообще `Template` для `UserControl`'а? Почему не просто так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426399/10105

Comment: И снова-таки непонятно, зачем вам стиль для кнопки, если она уже в `Template`'е.

Comment: Блин, я просто на самом деле путаюсь. Я смотрел всякие исходники, много видел, что так делают, и просто решил сам так делать. Если Template для UserControl'а не надо объявлять, то не буду. Буду прям UserControl'е контролы объявлять

Comment: Можно и так, и так. В большинстве случаев можно без `Template`. Есть случаи, когда Template нужен, например, если у вашего `UserControl`'а должен быть контент, как у `Window`. Но если он не нужен, без него проще.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы по стандарту, у этого UserControl'а, такие свойства, как Background, Foreground, и другие, были одинаковыми для вложенных контролов - TextBox и Button. Но если мне вздумается, я бы хотел иметь возможность написать стили для этих контролов по отдельности

Comment: Окей, ну хорошо, то есть, вы хотите стиль для кнопки заинжектить снаружи? Ну так почему бы не определить его как DependencyProperty?

Comment: Можно как `DependencyProperty`. Я тоже об этом думал. Мой вопрос звучал: "Как правильно делают такие вещи". Если реализовать это правильно через `DependencyProperty`, то так и буду делать в дальнейшем. Спасибо

Comment: @VladD что-то я совсем запутался, что мне надо. Эта тема вопроса связана тесно с вот этой темой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751954/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2 Суть в том, что мне нужно сделать несколько стилей для моего SearchBox'а. Стили могут воздействовать как на кнопку внутри SearchBox'а, так и на весь SearchBox в целом. Как такое сделать?

Comment: А, вот что вы хотите. Ну тут есть несколько путей. Можно с DependencyProperty, можно проще. Доберусь до компьютера, расскажу.

Comment: @VladD просто мне хочется сделать все это более менее универсально, чтобы применять в нескольких приложениях. Но тут, я так понимаю, нужно найти грань, когда надо остановится. Я пока не могу ее найти. У меня получается 3 UserControl'а - InputBox, SearchBox, SideMenu. SideMenu содержит в себе SearchBox. Я думаю, что в SideMenu можно уже настраивать внешний вид для частного использования его в программе. Как Вы думаете? А вот InputBox и SearchBox нужно сделать как можно более универсально

Comment: Можно, да, не вопрос. Я отпишусь, когда буду свободен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько путей. Например, можно через стили в ресурсах.

Пишем вот такой контрол:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.TestUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource TestUCButtonStyle}" Content="Button"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TestUCTextStyle}" Text="Text"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Стили `TestUCButtonStyle` поставляем через ресурсы. Для этого в `App.xaml` кладём стили:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:TestUC" x:Key="RedStyle">
        <!-- определяем внутренние стили -->
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TestUCButtonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TestUCTextStyle">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="local:TestUC" x:Key="SquareStyle">
        <!-- определяем внутренние стили -->
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TestUCButtonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualWidth,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TestUCTextStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <!-- и меняем свойства -->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
    </Style>
    <!-- устанавливаем стиль по умолчанию -->
    <Style TargetType="local:TestUC" BasedOn="{StaticResource RedStyle}"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Получаем:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:TestUC/>
    <local:TestUC Style="{StaticResource SquareStyle}"/>
    <local:TestUC Style="{StaticResource RedStyle}" Background="Yellow"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Результат:

[image: по-моему, эти цвета ужасны]

Comment: Вы предложили поменять стили у внутренних контролов, за счет определения `Style="{DynamicResource название стиля}"` для каждого такого контрола внутри UserControl. Но теперь мы должны точно знать название стиля, чтобы переопределить его! Тоесть, если я отдам этот UserControl другому человеку, и он в свою очередь захочет переопределить стиль у внутренней кнопки, то ему точно нужно будет знать название стиля, которое идет после слова `DynamicResource`

Comment: @Bretbas: Ну это да. Имя стиля становится при этом частью API. Если хотите более строгую альтернативу, то нужно определить стили как DependencyProperty у контрола, и привязывать из не по ключу, а через TemplateBinding.

Comment: В моем случае получается, мне нужно сделать `DependencyProperty` стиля для кнопки, чтобы дать возможность пользователю устанавливать его внешне. Так?

Comment: @Bretbas: Можно установить внешне, а можно и через стиль для всего контрола.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответы

Comment: @Bretbas: Пожалуйста!